# Use findOneAndUpdate $pull and populate does not update or Populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**This is my data:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("594e762b03cc52508686ceef"),
    "_members" : [ 
        "59527bd5e521801bf07eab98", 
        "594ecca47a699d1775c2a2db"
    ],
}
```

I want to delete `59527bd5e521801bf07eab98` from `_members`.

**PostSchema:**

```
const PostsSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    _members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }],
    // ...
})
```

**UserSchema:**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    posts : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'post' }],
    // ...
})
```

**Find And Update:**

```
let id = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)
let member = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.member)
let populateQuery = [
    {path:'_members', select:'_id'}
]

Post.
findOneAndUpdate(
    {'_id' : id} ,
    {
       $pull: { '_members': { '_id': member }}
     },
     {'new': true}
).
populate(populateQuery).
exec(
  function (err, data) {
    res.send(data)
  }
);
```

Comment: When asking questions, please include the question itself as well as any error message you are seeing. It's not clear what is not working for you: is it connection problem, is it the client error, syntax error, etc.?

Comment: @Eye It could have been stated more clearly but the "error" in this case is that the `.populate()` call does not do what it should and retrieve the related data. Which is what the point of the question is. Amended the title to reflect this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interestingly "population" only seems to work by specifying the `model` option to [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) in this case.

Also you only need supply the `member` directly to `$pull` as the `_id` is not actually a property, until "populated". The `"_members"` array is simply an array of `ObjectId` values within the `Post` itself. So supply the input directly:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'_id' : id} ,
  {
    $pull: { '_members': member }
  },
  {'new': true}
)
.populate({path:'_members', select:'_id', model: 'user' })
.exec(function(err,post) {
  if (err) throw err; // or something
  res.send(post)
})
```

Or with Promises

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'_id' : id} ,
  {
    $pull: { '_members':  member }
  },
  {'new': true}
)
.populate({path:'_members', select:'_id', model: 'user' })
.then(post => res.send(post))
.catch(err => console.error(err));  // or something
```

Alternately call [`Model.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) instead:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'_id' : id} ,
  {
    $pull: { '_members': member }
  },
  {'new': true}
).exec(function(err,post) {
  if (err) throw err; // or something

  Post.populate(post, {path:'_members', select:'_id', model: 'user' },function(err,post) {
    if (err) throw err; // or something
    res.send(post);   // now populated
  }
})
```

Or alternately using Promises:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  {'_id' : id} ,
  {
    $pull: { '_members': member }
  },
  {'new': true}
)
.then(post => Post.populate(post, {path:'_members', select:'_id', model: 'user' }))
.then(post => res.send(post))      // also populated
.catch(err => console.error(err))    // or whichever
```

Somewhat unsure about why you want to call `.populate()` when you are only asking to return the `_id` field which is already embedded in the document, but that's another case. With the `model` option the population actually takes place here.

---

As a self contained demonstration:

```
const async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

const relSchema = new Schema({ c: String });
const testSchema = new Schema({
  a: String,
  b: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, rel: 'Rel' }]
})

const Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);
const Rel = mongoose.model('Rel', relSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

async.series(
  [
    (callback) =>
      async.each(mongoose.models,(model,callback) =>
        model.remove({},callback),callback),

    (callback) =>
      async.waterfall(
        [

          (callback) => Rel.create([{ c: 2 },{ c: 3 },{ c: 4 }],callback),


          (rels,callback) => Test.create({ a: 1, b: rels },(err,test) => {
            if (err) callback(err);
            log(test);
            callback(err,test.b.slice(1,3))
          }),

          (rels,calback) =>
            Test.findOneAndUpdate(
              { 'a': 1 },
              { '$pull': { 'b': rels[0] } },
              { 'new': true }
            )
            .populate({ path: 'b', model: 'Rel' })
            .exec((err,test) => {
              if (err) callback(err);
              log(test);
              callback(err);
            })

        ],
        callback
      )

  ],
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
)
```

And the output:

```
Mongoose: tests.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: rels.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: rels.insert({ c: '2', _id: ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec7"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: rels.insert({ c: '3', _id: ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec8"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: rels.insert({ c: '4', _id: ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec9"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: tests.insert({ a: '1', _id: ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2eca"), b: [ ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec7"), ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec8"), ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec9") ], __v: 0 })
{
  "__v": 0,
  "a": "1",
  "_id": "595714579afd8860e56d2eca",
  "b": [
    "595714579afd8860e56d2ec7",
    "595714579afd8860e56d2ec8",
    "595714579afd8860e56d2ec9"
  ]
}
Mongoose: tests.findAndModify({ a: '1' }, [], { '$pull': { b: ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec8") } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: rels.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec7"), ObjectId("595714579afd8860e56d2ec9") ] } }, { fields: {} })
{
  "_id": "595714579afd8860e56d2eca",
  "a": "1",
  "__v": 0,
  "b": [
    {
      "_id": "595714579afd8860e56d2ec7",
      "c": "2",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "595714579afd8860e56d2ec9",
      "c": "4",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @user1788781 You can thank me by using your newly acquired ["upvote privileges"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)